# Cargar foto en móviles en vez de video

Tags: html5, css

Tengo un video en la portada de mi web de esta forma:

```
<section id="portada">
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="video_background" preload="auto" muted />
   <source src="videos/video_portada.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="videos/video_web.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video/>
</section>
```

Quisiera que cuando la página cargase desde un móvil se cargase una foto en vez del video.

Estoy probando así:

```
    <section id="portada">
    <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="video_background" preload="none" muted />
      <source id="video-mp4" src="" type="video/mp4" />
      <source id="video-webm" src="" type="video/webm" /> 
    </video>
<script type="text/javascript">  

  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 768) {

    document.querySelector("#video-mp4").src = "videos/video_portada.mp4";
    document.querySelector('#video-webm').src = "videos/video_web.webm";    
  }

</script>
    <img src="images/preboda/vertical_2.jpg" id="foto_portada" />
</section>
```

Mostrando con media queries la imagen o el video:

```
#foto_portada{
  display: none;
}

#video_background{ display: block; }

@media (max-width:768px) {
#video_background{
   display: none;
}

#foto_portada{
   display: block;
}
```

}​

Comment: @aldanux estoy probando con safari o chrome y en ambos no me muestra el video

Comment: Te funciona este [ejemplo](http://output.jsbin.com/bijeno)? En verdad no necesitas el `@media`.. mete la imagen en el atributo poster y tendrás la imagen igual si es en el dispositivo móvil...

Comment: Pues así con ese ejemplo la página me carga mucho más rápido en los dispositivos móviles y puedo dar formato a la imagen que muestro en el div.

Comment: Si lo puedes dar formato y tal... pero eso no importa ahora... te funciona el [ejemplo](http://output.jsbin.com/bijeno) en el movil y navegador? - @JavierManzano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes tener los dos (el video y la imagen) en tu html e ir mostrándolos según desees mediante media queries:

```
<section id="portada">
<video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="video_background" preload="auto" muted />
   <source src="videos/video_portada.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="videos/video_web.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video/>
<img id="foto" src="loquesea.png">
</section>
```

Por ejemplo puedes partir que video este visible y la imagen no:

```
#foto{
   display: none;
}

#video{
   display: block;
}
```

Y después para una anchura determinada de tu navegador hacer que el video se oculte y se muestre la imagen. Por ejemplo, que entre 250px y 500px se muestre la foto y se oculte el video.

```
@media (max-width:500px) and (min-width:250px) {
    #video{
       display: none;
    }

    #foto{
       display: block;
    }
}​
```

Puede que no sea la forma más "limpia" de hacerlo pero puede servirte para tus especificaciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo malo de hacerlo así es que carga el video también con lo que ralentiza la página. Mientras encuentro otra solución esta me vale.

Comment: @JavierManzano Sí, como he indicado en la respuesta, a mi parecer es un poco "sucia". Sin embargo, es la única forma que conozco hasta el momento. Estaré atento a tu pregunta de todas formas por si hay alguien que pone alguna respuesta con la que se pueda hacer esto de una forma mucho más simple y clara :)

Comment: @JavierManzano Los dispositivos móviles no cargan los videos de primeras para evitar incurrir en uso de datos innecesario, por lo que realmente no debería haber ralentización (porque no se está cargando nada). Pero si es algo que quieres evitar, puedes ponerle el valor "none" al `preload`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Muchas gracias, ya he cambiado el atributo por "none", supongo que para un video de 10Mb no es necesario precargarlo para que no se trabe por que vaya más rápido que la propia carga.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - He editado mi respuesta porque cuando he leído tu comentario investigue un poco porque me recordaba algo que no era siempre así y por lo visto cuando se tiene el atributo autoplay se ignora el preload.

Comment: Con ese codigo no te garantiza que sea un movil o un pc, sino que te garantiza el tamaño de la ventana del navegador

Comment: @AlbertoMier Sí, de hecho, en ningún sitio he indicado que te detecte que sea PC o móvil. Simplemente es un tipo de workaround que, para algunos casos concretos, le puede ser útil al OP. La verdad que desconozco si se puede hacer directamente con HTML y CSS como indica el OP sin usar nada de JS o JQuery. Por eso me intenté ajustar lo máximo posible a las especificaciones del OP, dentro de lo que yo sé.

Comment: @AlbertoMier Sí, de hecho, en ningún sitio he indicado que te detecte que sea PC o móvil. Simplemente es un tipo de workaround que, para algunos casos concretos, le puede ser útil al OP. La verdad que desconozco si se puede hacer directamente con HTML y CSS como indica el OP sin usar nada de JS o JQuery. Por eso me intenté ajustar lo máximo posible a las especificaciones del OP, dentro de lo que yo sé.

Answer (score 1):

Alguien preguntó algo parecido en SOen y la respuesta que le dieron fue esta:

Puedes añadir esto: `poster="placeholder.png"`

```html
<video width="470" height="255" poster="placeholder.png" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <object data="video.mp4" width="470" height="255">
    <embed src="video.swf" width="470" height="255">
    </object>
</video>
```

Ruta original de la pregunta:
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075875/how-to-set-the-thumbnail-image-on-html5-video)

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Eso sirve para mostrar una foto antes de que cargue el video.

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación Mozilla Foundation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/video#attr-preload) dice:

> El atributo autoplay  tiene prioridad sobre preload si se desea
>   reproducir automáticamente un video, el navegador obviamente tendrá
>   que descargarlo.

Es decir, cuando usas `autoplay` el atributo `preload` ***se ignora***.

Entonces para evitar la carga del video en dispositivos móviles lo puedes hacer con javascript.

En el ejemplo carga el `source` del video sólo si el tamaño de la ventana es mayor de `500px`, lo contrario, se ve la imagen del atributo `poster`.

**[Ver Demo](http://output.jsbin.com/yanadas)**

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" id="video_background" poster="http://placehold.it/560x320" muted>
    <source id="video-mp4" src="" type="video/mp4">
    <source id="video-webm" src="" type="video/webm">
</video>

<script>  

  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 500) {

    var videoSource = 'http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small';

    document.querySelector('#video-mp4').src = videoSource + '.mp4';
    document.querySelector('#video-webm').src = videoSource + '.webm';    
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Y cual imagen quieres cargar? Pon en el poster la imagen que quieras. No? Y lo de mp4 y webm te lo arreglo ahora cuando esté en casa...- @JavierManzano

Comment: No sé por qué motivo no me carga el video en ninguno de los casos.

Comment: Que navegador usas? - @JavierManzano

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dice el compañero aldanux, si no quieres que se cargue en la vista de usuario, no lo cargues.

Lo optimo sería evaluar el dispositivo:
https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js/

y si quieres afinar más, la conexión: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988051/checking-someones-bandwidth-and-loading-content-based-on-it

A partir de ahí puedes cargar dinámicamente los contenidos optimizados y a tu elección.